# Написание ИИ на php

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, php

Сразу попрошу воздержаться от плевков ))

Да, я понимаю, что `php` не совсем тот самый язык, на котором можно это делать, но все же, хочу попробовать.

Нужно сделать простую болталку, которая будет отвечать на хотя бы 70% вопросов "в тему"? и задавать свои.
Хотелось бы услышать мнения спецов.

[То, что уже существует](http://alice.pandorabots.com/) - хочу примерно тоже, но по-русски.
Как оно работает у них, реальный пример:

---

> Victor: how are you doing?
>
> ALICE: Not too bad.
>
> Victor: great
>
> ALICE: Thanks for the compliment.
>
> Victor: what's new?
>
> ALICE: I am chatting with clients on
> the internet.
>
> Victor: what is your name?
>
> ALICE: I am called ALICE.
>
> Victor: My name is Victor
>
> ALICE: Hi there Victor.
>
> Victor: you remember my name?
>
> ALICE: You said your name is Victor?
>
> Victor: yes
>
> ALICE: Really.

---

**Подчеркну**: нужно **не** пояснение тех части, а **алгоритм работы.**

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: http://www.alicebot.org/aiml/aaa/

Comment: Есть разница для английского и русского. Русский язык - флективный (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Флективные_языки). Поэтому ваш бот должен нетривиальным образом согласовывать флексии (суффиксы, окончания). Для этого нужно знать структуру исходной мысли и уметь преобразовывать ее в фразу. Это определенно сложнее, чем с английским. Словариком и простым перцептроном не обойдешься, ведь даже Google Translater лажает страшно, наверняка используя технологии посложнее. Ну либо бот должен первой репликой писать что-то типа: здравствуйте, я не есть русский.

Comment: По сути это Алиса, Сири и Гугл

Answer (score 7):

1. Делаешь большой словарь(можно хранить в мускле) фраз-ответов.
2. Делаешь словарь ключевых слов и фраз
3. Парсишь фразу от пользователя
4. Выбираешь контрольные слова
5. Делаешь запрос в бд за ответом
6. Профит

Вариант 2:

1. Нанимаешь бабулек или китайцев
2. Садишь на другую сторону чата
3. Они отвечают на все вопросы
4. Профит

**ГЗВ**

Интересный [образец](http://ru.akinator.com/).

Comment: дополнил вопрос. вариант 2 заманчив, но не поможет мне вырасти как программисту )
вариант 1 не гибок.

Comment: You said: f@ck
A.L.I.C.E.: That is deep.

Comment: You said: how old are you?

A.L.I.C.E.: I was activated in 1995.

Comment: думаешь она работает по другому?

Comment: я дописал только что пример общения.

Comment: думаю по другому.. почитай пример, только что так с ней поговорил.

Comment: врятли, принцип тот же, просто добавлены фишки, типа запоминание ключевых фраз, дат, событий, причем не исключено, что там есть движок "самообучения"(как например в плагине к джаберу - "говорун+"). Т.е. весь ИИ заключен в накапливание фраз, ключевых вопросов и ответов

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов принцип алгоритма того джинна очень простой: вбиты всевозможные персонажи, у них есть определенные характеристики (мульт герой - ДА, аниме - НЕТ, человек - ДА, убийца - НЕТ, пропеллер есть - ДА --- Я знаю - это Карлсон!), подбивая все да и нет можно сделать определенный вывод, ничего сложного не вижу, если честно..то, что нужно мне - бот, отвечающий на вопросы, и задающий их, простое общение, без уклона на спец тематики, ALICE - самое то, как пример.

Comment: Зато второй вариант имеет ненулевые шансы пройти тест Тьюринга)

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже пытался сделать "умного" бота на сайт. Делал базы данных, пробовал функции с ответами. Но это громоздкая работа. Всё таки для таких вещей лучше использовать другие языки программирования. Хотя, чтобы поломать мозг - можно и делать на PHP.

Некоторые действия:

- Нужна база слов без склонений и окончаний
- Нужен парсер, который будет убирать окончания
- Нужно over9999 часов, чтобы делать ответы на вопросы
- Нужно около месяца общаться через свой чат, чтобы вытаскивать оттуда фразы, которые использовались, и возможные ответы. Тем самым Вы обучите бота обычным разговорам.
- Нужно построить дерево фраз (как на iii)
- Установить уже сделанного и проверенного бота от другого создателя и удалить всё своё индусство

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов а вы знаете уже сделанного бота, хотя бы на половину такого же умного как ALICE говорящего на русском языке? я с радостью взгляну

Comment: посмотри у меня в ответе линку

Comment: спс щас гляну

Comment: http://82f85802-7845-4bbf-9d71-d796521bd9bd.iii.ru/
Вот, тут можно бесплатно создать бота, что я и сделал. Сам могу обучать его и тд. Удобно. Хотел подобное сделать

Comment: ну это не то.. хотя тоже интересно. и, я думаю, это легче сделать)

Comment: Почему легче? Он умно отвечает на фразы, даже загадки задает :D

Comment: Эмиль, я знаю про него, когда я пытался с ним общаться (пару лет назад) он был ужасно глуп, не знаю, может сейчас поумнее.

Comment: Ozim, я так понимаю, что принцип алгоритма у него Вам понятен? Если да, то скажите, что можно сделать по-другому? Какой другой алгоритм можете предложить?

Answer (score 0):

Берем нейронную сеть, есть интересная библиотека (работает с кучей языков, в том числе php, через api): http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/ пишем ИИ, учим, захватываем мир. Параллельно можно и чатик замутить.